# PHP HTTP Proxy Server

Tags: php, proxy

Does anyone know of a PHP script that runs as a proxy server (WITHOUT using a web server like Apache)? I am looking for a PHP based one so I can edit/modify the traffic that goes through it (for security reasons). The closest thing I've found is philtron (http://philtron.sourceforge.net/), but this seems to be an outdated project and no longer works with PHP5.

Comment: PHP wouldn't be exactly my first choice to implement a complete server, so I'd say your chances of finding one are probably slim.

Comment: Yes. See my answer below. It's dead simple to implement an http proxy in PHP using the built in web server. You can then modify the pages like you did with philtron, but using updated technology for parsing and manipulating the data. . . Like PHP:DOMDocument, passing javascript through node and transforming it with esprima, cleaning up the html with html tidy, etc.

Comment: [Here is a simple script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17040356), which works via a proxied HTTPS conversation. I've got [this library working too](https://github.com/jenssegers/php-proxy), but only in HTTP mode, whereas I am looking for `CONNECT` support. The latter looks much more stable and tested, but I am guessing it cannot run as an HTTPS proxy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Nanoweb](http://nanoweb.si.kz/), a web server implemented in PHP. It comes with [mod_proxy](http://nanoweb.si.kz/manual/mod_proxy.html). Though manipulating the traffic will require a few more code changes. It wasn't intended for that. OTOH it's the most HTTP/1.1 compliant PHP solution you will find.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big PHP expert and I'm sure one can implement webs server in PHP but that's not how it is done. If you don't want to use Apache try using `nginx` (lightweight, easy to change, etc).

Nevertheless I think your requirements are weird. It's like saying you want to write an HTML page in Assembly language. Doable but not the best way. If you need something like a proxy that can sniff on traffic you should use `haproxy` and modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I too needed an HTTP proxy written in PHP, so that I can integrate it into a project that needs to interact with a 3rd party server that didn't implement CORS.

Here's my result. The script is tested with PHP-7.4.

```php
<?php
 $target = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], strlen($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]));
 #$url = "http://localhost:8008$target"; 
 $url = "https://example.com/$target"; 
 $req = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

 $hopbyhop = [];
 
 function handler_header($req, $header)
 {
   global $hopbyhop;
   header($header);
   $matches = [];
   if( preg_match('/^connection:(.*)$/i', $header, $matches) )
   {
     $hopts = explode(",", $matches[1]);
     foreach( $hopts as $hopt )
     {
       $ho = trim($hopt);
       $hopbyhop[] = $ho;
     }
   }
   return strlen($header);
 }

 function header_readycb()
 {
   global $hopbyhop;
   foreach( $hopbyhop as $hhdr )
   {
     header_remove($hhdr);
   }
 }

 header_register_callback("header_readycb");
 curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "handler_header");
 curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);

 $hdr = [];

 $prefix = "HTTP_";
 $conn = "HTTP_CONNECTION";
 $connopt = $_SERVER[$conn] ?? "";
 $connopts = explode(",", $connopt);
 foreach( $connopts as &$opt )
 {
   $opt = trim($opt);
   $opt = strtoupper($opt);
   $opt = preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]]/', "_", $opt);
 }

 foreach( $_SERVER as $k => $v )
 {
   if( substr($k, 0, strlen($prefix)) !== $prefix ) continue;
   if( $k === "HTTP_HOST" ) continue;

   $i = 0;
   for($i=0; $i<count($connopts); $i++)
     if( "HTTP_".$connopts[$i] === $k ) break;
   if( $i < count($connopts) ) continue;

   $hdr[] = strtr(substr($k, strlen($prefix)), "_", "-").": $v";
 }

 curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $hdr);

 curl_exec($req);
```

You can register different callbacks using `curl_setopt` to capture and modify the request and the response.