# cURL as proxy, deal with HTTPS/CONNECT method

Tags: php, sockets, curl, ssl, proxy

This script listens on an IP/port and intends to act as a HTTP(S) proxy.

Requests to HTTP URLs work fine, but I'm stumbling on how to deal with HTTPS requests and more specifically, an SSLv3 handshake after the client sends a CONNECT request to the proxy.

The closest I've came to what *looks like an answer* is:

- CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL libcurl option to tunnel data between client and target server
- stream_socket_enable_crypto() to possibly "do stuff" with the encrypted data

I'm really not sure, so a pointer as to how to deal with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a sample request: http://pastebin.com/xkWhGyjW

```
<?php

class proxy {

    static $server;
    static $client;

    static function headers($str) { // Parses HTTP headers into an array
        $tmp = preg_split("'\r?\n'",$str);
        $output = array();
        $output[] = explode(' ',array_shift($tmp));
        $post = ($output[0][0] == 'POST' ? true : false);

            foreach($tmp as $i => $header) {
                if($post && !trim($header)) {
                    $output['POST'] = $tmp[$i+1];
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    $l = explode(':',$header,2);
                    $output[$l[0]] = $l[0].': '.ltrim($l[1]);
                }
            }
        return $output;
    }

    public function output($curl,$data) {
        socket_write(proxy::$client,$data);
        return strlen($data);
    }
}




$ip = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 50000;

proxy::$server = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option(proxy::$server,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,1);
socket_bind(proxy::$server,$ip,50000);
socket_getsockname(proxy::$server,$ip,$port);
socket_listen(proxy::$server);

while(proxy::$client = socket_accept(proxy::$server)) {

    $input = socket_read(proxy::$client,4096);
    preg_match("'^([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\s([^\r\n]+)'ims",$input,$request);
    $headers = proxy::headers($input);

        echo $input,"\n\n";
            if(preg_match("'^CONNECT '",$input)) { // HTTPS
                // Tell the client we can deal with this
                socket_write(proxy::$client,"HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n\r\n");
                // Client sends binary data here (SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello?)
                // socket_read(proxy::$client,4096);
                // ?
            }
            else { // HTTP

                        $input = preg_replace("'^([^\s]+)\s([a-z]+://)?[a-z0-9\.\-]+'","\\1 ",$input);
                        $curl = curl_init($request[2]);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,15);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, array("proxy","output"));
                        curl_exec($curl);
                        curl_close($curl);
            }
    socket_close(proxy::$client);
}
socket_close(proxy::$server);


?>
```

Comment: Could you post on pastebin your code for HTTP URL requests?

Comment: Of course... I am using cURL command line to test. http://pastebin.com/xkWhGyjW

Comment: Have you tried other sites than google.com (according to your pastebin)? (see here http://superuser.com/questions/404116/cannot-connect-to-website-ssl-handshaking-fails) 
And have you tried to connect without the proxy, i.e. `curl -L -i -v "https://www.google.com/"`? 
What's the output if you add `--trace tracetxt.tmp` to your curl call, when using your proxy and when connecting directly? Perhaps the diff of the traces might help?

Comment: yes, thanks. I'd tried --trace to get an idea of the data being sent but didn't give me any more direction about how to handle that data between the connections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're writing a HTTP proxy server in PHP. The `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` option is used when you want to connect to a proxy server using the PHP cURL library and use `CONNECT` instead of `GET`. In this case it's not relevant.

When your proxy server (PROXY) receives the `CONNECT` request, it should connect to the specified host (ENDPOINT) using `socket_create` and `socket_connect`. Once the connection is established, let the client (CLIENT) know by sending `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established`. After that, you'll want to copy all data that the ENDPOINT sends to PROXY to the CLIENT and all data that the CLIENT sends to PROXY to the ENDPOINT.

Using cURL like in your example will create multiple connections. To handle multiple connections, I've used `pcntl_fork`, which forks  a new process on every `CONNECT` request.

Here's a working example:

```
<?php

class proxy {

    static $server;
    static $client;

    static function headers($str) { // Parses HTTP headers into an array
        $tmp = preg_split("'\r?\n'",$str);
        $output = array();
        $output[] = explode(' ',array_shift($tmp));
        $post = ($output[0][0] == 'POST' ? true : false);

            foreach($tmp as $i => $header) {
                if($post && !trim($header)) {
                    $output['POST'] = $tmp[$i+1];
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    $l = explode(':',$header,2);
                    $output[$l[0]] = $l[0].': '.ltrim($l[1]);
                }
            }
        return $output;
    }

    public function output($curl,$data) {
        socket_write(proxy::$client,$data);
        return strlen($data);
    }
}




$ip = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 50000;

proxy::$server = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option(proxy::$server,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,1);
socket_bind(proxy::$server,$ip,50000);
socket_getsockname(proxy::$server,$ip,$port);
socket_listen(proxy::$server);

while(proxy::$client = socket_accept(proxy::$server)) {

    $input = socket_read(proxy::$client,4096);
    preg_match("'^([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\s([^\r\n]+)'ims",$input,$request);
    $headers = proxy::headers($input);

        echo $input,"\n\n";
            if(preg_match("'^CONNECT ([^ ]+):(\d+) '",$input,$match)) { // HTTPS
                // fork to allow multiple connections
                if(pcntl_fork())
                    continue;

                $connect_host = $match[1];
                $connect_port = $match[2];

                // connect to endpoint
                $connection = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
                if(!socket_connect($connection, gethostbyname($connect_host), $connect_port))
                    exit;

                // let the client know that we're connected
                socket_write(proxy::$client,"HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n\r\n");

                // proxy data
                $all_sockets = array($connection, proxy::$client);
                $null = null;
                while(($sockets = $all_sockets)
                      && false !== socket_select($sockets, $null, $null, 10)
                ) {
                    // can we read from the client without blocking?
                    if(in_array(proxy::$client, $sockets)) {
                        $buf = null;
                        socket_recv(proxy::$client, $buf, 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT);
                        echo "CLIENT => ENDPOINT (" . strlen($buf) . " bytes)\n";
                        if($buf === null)
                            exit;
                        socket_send($connection, $buf, strlen($buf), 0);
                    }

                    // can we read from the endpoint without blocking?
                    if(in_array($connection, $sockets)) {
                        $buf = null;
                        socket_recv($connection, $buf, 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT);
                        echo "ENDPOINT => CLIENT (" . strlen($buf) . " bytes)\n";
                        if($buf === null)
                            exit;
                        socket_send(proxy::$client, $buf, strlen($buf), 0);
                    }
                }

                exit;
            }
            else { // HTTP

                        $input = preg_replace("'^([^\s]+)\s([a-z]+://)?[a-z0-9\.\-]+'","\\1 ",$input);
                        $curl = curl_init($request[2]);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,15);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, array("proxy","output"));
                        curl_exec($curl);
                        curl_close($curl);
            }
    socket_close(proxy::$client);
}
socket_close(proxy::$server);
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this later today. I fork already but just removed it for posting here, as the main focus is on dealing with HTTPS connections acting as a proxy / and the CONNECT method. Just a note, forking like that will leave zombie process, using something like pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) is useful... and the client/server socket needs to be closed by the parent as well as the child.

Comment: Yup, you'll have to improve the code for safety. It was more of a quick-and-dirty example of the desired functionality.

Comment: I can confirm this works too. I've been surprised at how hard it has been to find a working PHP HTTPS proxy implementation on Packagist. I'll use this to start with, but something that has tests and has GitHub stars would be very reassuring. Nevertheless, thanks Albert for your work.

Comment: However, there is a bug in `proxy::headers` for the HTTP proxy, and the code emits a lot of warnings under PHP 7.1. I have tidied this up, and will make it available on GitHub at some point.